# aligned div to a span

Tags: html, css

I would like to be able to align a div to a span. For example:

```
<div style="some magic">foo bar<div> 
<p>this is a random text with <span class="stressed">stressed phrase</span> in it</p>
```

The result to be something like:

```
                              foo bar
this is a random text with stressed phrase in it
```

where the content of the div is centered to the text in the span.

Comment: I'd say that you cannot do that with your current html structure and css. You should put div inside the span, and then offset it with margin-top, or something like that. Or use javascript.

Comment: nesting div in span does not seem to be correct in CSS 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJXE3/3/

HTML

```
<p>this is a random text with <span class="stressed"><span class="somemagic">foo bar</span>stressed phrase</span> in it</p>
```

CSS

```
.somemagic {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: -25px;       // if stressed text is smaller you need a negative margin
                              // either set manually if text size is known or calculated
}                             // and set with javascript
.stressed {
    position: relative;
}
```

You also might need to add a margin to your "p" (or an extra line break) so any element above won't get covered by the "somemagic" text.

UPDATE 2

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rJXE3/4/

I found another option how to set the CSS (and no javascript required)

```
.somemagic {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: -100%;
}
.stressed {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: this does not work if the stressed text is shorter than the comment
http://jsfiddle.net/rJXE3/1/